# Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server HP Print issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, printing

For a few weeks I have the problem that when people print on the terminal server to HP printers (most of them are) and the document contains a image the print job get stuck. It will try to restart the job but fails everytime.

When switching the driver to the models specific driver or back to universal print driver pcl 6 all jobs will resume printing. Only to have this problem again in a few hours.

When this problem occurs a print spool restart won't help.

- Server 2008 R2 Terminal Server
- Printers are connected locally on the terminal server via TCP/IP, so no redirection.
- Plain text does not seem to get stuck
- Pdf with a image, word with a image, or just a image will get the printer queue stuck
- Display of the printer will say printing to quickly disappear when it gets stuck.

Printers we use.

- 3x HP Color LaserJet M477
- 2x HP Color LaserJet CM3220
- 1x HP M402dn

Kyocera printer don't seem to be affected.

Answer (score 2):

Printing issues are not uncommon on RDS/TS, unfortunately. If you're past basic troubleshooting, I would just remove all drivers, print monitors, printers, and reset the printing system back to a clean state. Here's a PS script I found:

https://github.com/jdickson289/Print-Reset-Tool/

Unless there was a need otherwise, I would stick to only using a universal print driver since many printer specific drivers seem to not be thoroughly tested with RDS.

Comment: Agreed. This answer does not solve the root problem, but it is good advice. When connecting through RDP/TS, each printer should have a duplicate labeled `(redirected)`. In our environment, we have to be careful to *not* choose the redirected ones, or it's anyone's guess where the print job is going to go.

Comment: Thank you Genericname12, I applied the printer reset tool and only used the HP UPD PCL6 on a test terminal server, some users are now checking if printing works okay. Hopefully this fixes the issues we are having.

Will get back to you if it did.